# What is difference between blog id and site id?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

The going through the mu functions source I come across references to two different ids for sub-blogs - site id and blog ids. In what context is each used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **site_id** = the ID of the parent site (the domain, eg. wordpress.com)
- **blog_id** = the ID of the parent site's blog(s) (usually sub-domains, eg mary.wordress.com)

Comment: Yep. the admin are use of the word site is not the same as the db use of the word site.

Comment: I just wanted to add my own note in here for anyone who stumbles on this. wp_site has the main site in MU, and wp_blogs contains sub-sites.

Answer (score 5):

In a Multisite install (and also since WordPress 3), you can have a several **blogs** (identified in the database model by `blog_id`) within one **site** (identified in the database model by `site_id`).

The thing that I found confusing in this context, though, is that most of WordPress code and documentation will use a terminology that differs from the database model. They refer to a *blog* using the word **site**, and to a *site* using the word **network**.

For example, [this section of the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) refers to the Site URL (as defined in the `WP_SITEURL` constant), which really is the URL of the blog URL in multisite context.